# How to set controls inside ASP panel to Display:none when panel is set to Display:None

Tags: c#, html, panel

I have set up multiple panels inside controls to show/hide things depending on a version number. I have code that goes through panels on the page and if the version number does not match then the panel is set to **Display:None**. I know the panels are set to **Display:none** because I verified it in Chrome Developer tools while debugging.  The problem is that the controls wrapped inside the panels are still shown on the page. Below is how the panel is setup in the html and the code that sets the panels to display:none. Please advise. Thank you.

It works if visible is set to false for the panel however I still need the controls to render on the page even if they arent shown.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" version="1" ID="property113_v1">
    <tr>
        <td class="asterisk">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="required">How to blank? </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2"><asp:RadioButtonList ID="property113" runat="server" RepeatDirection="horizontal" RepeatLayout="flow">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="property113Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="property113"
            ErrorMessage="" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="Page"><span class="validator">&nbsp;</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
    </tr></asp:Panel>



    foreach (Panel pnl in p)
    {

        if (pnl.Attributes["Version"] != null)
        {
            if (pnl.Attributes["Version"] == ver)
            {
                pnl.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "");
            }
            else
            {
                pnl.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none"); 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you are saying that child HTML elements of parent with `style="display:none"` are visible? That's somewhat hard to believe... showing resulting HTML that leads to this may help.

Comment: Inspect the rendered HTML and make sure that `style='display:none'` is actually rendered to the parent `div`. I would also suggest adding a CSS class instead of inline styles. If you don't need client side (browser) interaction with the hidden panels you can set `pnl.Visible="false"`.

Comment: Note your current code is going to result in invalid HTML, which may be part of your problem. `asp:Panel` renders a `div` which is an invalid  parent for `tr`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, the radio button and the td still appears on the page despite the panel being set to Display:None.

Comment: @JonP As stated above visible= false works however I need the controls inside the panels to still render. I checked and the div is set to Display:None but none of the controls are inside the div? What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code results in invalid html, `div` can not be a parent of `tr`. This is causing your problem, for a demo see: https://jsfiddle.net/4n6qkfzw/

You need to use the correct element `tbody`

Update your aspx to use similar too

```
<!-- use the tbody tag with runat=server here -->
<tbody runat="server" version="1" ID="property113_v1">
    <tr>
        <td class="asterisk">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="required">How to blank? </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2"><asp:RadioButtonList ID="property113" runat="server" RepeatDirection="horizontal" RepeatLayout="flow">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="property113Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="property113"
            ErrorMessage="" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="Page"><span class="validator">&nbsp;</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
    </tr></tbody>
```

Now update your code behind to something similar to:

```
List<HtmlGenericControl> tbodies = new List<HtmlGenericControl>{/*Populate your list here*/};
foreach (HtmlGenericControl tbody in tbodies)
{

    if (tbody.Attributes["version"] != null)
    {
        if (tbody.Attributes["version"] == ver)
        {
            tbody.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "");
        } /*Probably actually don't need the else statment
        else
        {
            pnl.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none"); 
        }
       */
    }
}
```